# ASMX WebService reverse engineering

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx

I am not able to produce following SOAP body response;

```
<soap:Body>
    <GetResponse xmlns="http://mycompany/service">
        <result>true</result>
        <data>Date to return</data>
        <errorMessage />
    </GetResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

Is it even possible do that using asmx WebService?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 on .NET 4 Framework.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Its about reverse engineering, I am wondering if this is possible to achive.

Comment: I am saying that you should not use an ASMX service unless you have no other choice.